# Last 1 to 2 digits of a int with a varible length int

Tags: sql

I am using SQL Server and I have an int that is 4 to 5 characters long.
I have a report that cast the first 3 digits as the location and last 1 to 2 digits as a cause.
So this is how they look

```
5142 = 514 = paint line 2 = paint to thin:
50528 = 505 = machining 28 = oblong hole:

SELECT [Suspect]
      ,left(Suspect,3) as SuspectOP
      ,Right(Suspect,2) as SuspectID
```

This query will return

```
5142 = SuspectOP = 514 SuspectID = 42
50528 = SuspectOP = 505 SuspectID = 28
```

So what i want is to read everything after the first 3 digits of the int.

Some of the things I have tried are as follows:
`Select Cast(Suspect as Varchar(5)), 
Substring(Suspect,3,2)`

And

`Select Suspect % 514 as SuspectID`

Which does work as long as the first 3 digits are always 514 which in my case aren't.

Comment: Ok. That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump your to-do/i-want lists

Comment: @MarcB That's a bit of a harsh way of saying it. Try to be nice to new users in future.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: then perhaps new users should actually READ the site faq that's presented when they ask their first question.

Comment: @booster281 Could you show us what you've tried? If we answered "write this code" questions all the time, we'd be writing entire programs for no pay, not just helping out people who want to learn.

Comment: Yes my question is how can I get everything after the first three digits.

Comment: @MarcB Bad forum habits are hard to shake. This community is not like many others. The OP (booster281) is not trying to spam, or to get us to write a program for him/her, so can we guide him/her instead of telling him/her off?

Comment: @boster281 Have you tried writing code to do this yet? Or are you just completely stuck?

Comment: i have tried SELECT cast(suspect as varchar(5)),
SUBSTRING(Suspect,3,2)

Comment: sorry keep hitting enter. I am new to actually asking questions in a forum.  Ill try to clean it up. As to trying to cast as a string then using a substring command it still tries to read it as a int.

Comment: Using `Select Suspect % 514 as SuspectID` works unless it doesn't start with 514 and I don't know if there is any single digit wildcards in a select statement.  If there is i could do `Suspect % 51_ as SuspectID`.

Comment: @boster281 Could you edit the code you've tried into the question? Comments aren't permanent, and not everyone reads them. (Oh, and Stack Overflow isn't like most "forums"; questions are separate from answers here, and you don't ask follow-up questions in answers.)

Comment: @boster281 I assume that your most recent comment was directed at Andrei Hirsu's answer; I posted a comment to notify him/her about it.

Comment: What is your DBMS? With SQL questions, always tag your DBMS.

Comment: this is just a user who never read all the string functions... RIGHT() is the function he needs to read about.

Comment: Don't store two different things in one field. If you see a SuspectOP and a SuspectID in that number, then it should not be stored as one number, but as two separate values.

Comment: @Hogan I started by using the RIGHT() Function which worked well until I went from looking at 1 digit to the right to needing to look at 1 or 2 due to more SuspectIDs.  Mr.Kettner is correct in saying I should have split the Suspect op and id. I am sure I had a great reason to combine the two at the time. All I can do is learn from mistakes.

Comment: @boster281 - that is awesome.  Most SO users don't learn anything when they can just ask another question, you made my day when you said you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a conditional operators based on the length like this:

```
SELECT 
    [Suspect]
    , SuspectOP = LEFT(Suspect,3)
    , SuspectID = CASE 
                     WHEN LEN(Suspect) = 5 THEN RIGHT(Suspect,2) 
                     ELSE RIGHT(Suspect, 1) 
                  END
```

Mind you, it's not ideal, you should really keep the values separate if your use case is like the one mentioned.

Comment: The OP posted a comment on the question that I think is directed at your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181643/last-1-to-2-digits-of-a-int-with-a-varible-length-int#comment67631174_40181643